# How to find the shortest path matrix?

Tags: r, tree, graph-theory, igraph

I have an weighted adjacency matrix `m` and I need the find the shortest path matrix. The expected result is:
[image]

```
library(igraph)

n = 8
m <- t(matrix(c(
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,
0,0,6,0,0,7,1,0,
0,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,4,0,0,8,0,0,3,
0,3,0,0,0,9,0,0),ncol=n))

g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")

V(g1)$names <-  letters[1:n]
plot(g1, vertex.label = V(g1)$names, edge.arrow.size=0.5)
```

My attept is:

```
path_name <- c()

for (i in c(1,2,6,8)){
for (path in all_simple_paths(g1, i, V(g1), mode="out")) {
       path_name <- c(path_name, paste(V(g1)[path]$names, collapse='')); 
}
}
path_name
    [1] "ah"   "ahb"  "ahf"  "ba"   "bah"  "bahf" "hb"   "hba"  "hf"
```

One can see that I have found the paths just for four nodes: 1, 2, 5, 6 with names a,  b, f, h. If we take a, b, h as a start node we can obtain 3 paths for each node while for h no path.

**Question.** How to reconstruct the paths for all nodes?
I don't found the Lee (wave) algoritms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
m <- d <- distances(g1, mode = "out")
for (i in row.names(d)) {
    for (j in colnames(d)) {
        if (i != j) {
            if (!is.infinite(d[i, j])) {
                m[i, j] <- paste0(names(shortest_paths(g1, i, j)$vpath[[1]]), collapse = "")
            } else {
                m[i,j] <- NA
            }
        } else {
            m[i, j] <- ""
        }
    }
}
```

and you will see the shortest-path matrix `m`

```
> m
  a     b     c     d      e     f      g      h
a ""    "ahb" NA    NA     NA    "ahf"  NA     "ah"
b "ba"  ""    NA    NA     NA    "bahf" NA     "bah"
c "ca"  "ceb" ""    "cd"   "ce"  "cdf"  "cdg"  "cdgh"
d "dga" "dgb" "dc"  ""     "dce" "df"   "dg"   "dgh"
e "eca" "eb"  "ec"  "ecd"  ""    "ecdf" "ecdg" "ecdgh"
f NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    ""     NA     NA
g "ga"  "gb"  "gec" "gecd" "ge"  "ghf"  ""     "gh"
h "hba" "hb"  NA    NA     NA    "hf"   NA     ""
```

Comment: I have run the code and add rownames(d) <- colnames(d) <- V(g1)$names before for-loop, but matrix m does not changed after for-loop.

Comment: @Nick When you create `g1`, you should use `V(g1)$name <-  letters[1:n]` to assign names to vertices, rather than `$names`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `igraph::all_shortest_paths` but, unless I am missing something, reconstructing the matrix is still tricky.

EDIT: cleaned up `purrr` section

```r
library(purrr)
library(igraph)
n = 8
m <- t(matrix(c(
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,
0,0,6,0,0,7,1,0,
0,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,4,0,0,8,0,0,3,
0,3,0,0,0,9,0,0),ncol=n))

g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")

V(g1)$names <-  letters[1:n]

v <- 1:n

mat <- matrix("",
              nrow = n,
              ncol = n,
              dimnames = list(V(g1)$names, V(g1)$names))

map(v, ~all_shortest_paths(g1, .x, v[-.x], mode = "out")) |>
  map(chuck, "res") |>
  compact() |>
  map_depth(~{V(g1)$names[as.vector(.x)]}, .depth = 2) |>
  flatten() |>
  walk(~{
    mat[first(.x), last(.x)] <<- paste(.x, collapse = "")
  })

mat
  
##>   a      b     c     d      e     f      g      h      
##> a ""     "ahb" ""    ""     ""    "ahf"  ""     "ah"   
##> b "ba"   ""    ""    ""     ""    "bahf" ""     "bah"  
##> c "ca"   "ceb" ""    "cd"   "ce"  "cdf"  "cdg"  "cdgh" 
##> d "dgba" "dgb" "dc"  ""     "dce" "df"   "dg"   "dgh"  
##> e "eca"  "eb"  "ec"  "ecd"  ""    "ecdf" "ecdg" "ecdgh"
##> f ""     ""    ""    ""     ""    ""     ""     ""     
##> g "gba"  "gb"  "gec" "gecd" "ge"  "ghf"  ""     "gh"   
##> h "hba"  "hb"  ""    ""     ""    "hf"   ""     ""
```

Comment: I have tried to repeate your code but I can't. I think the possible reason for difference is: how to calculate the shorters path -- w/o weights.

Comment: @Nick I don't fully get your comment. Do you mean it did not work on actual data? In order to avoid using weights you can try `all_shortest_paths(..., weights = NA)`

Comment: @Nick EDIT2: There was a misnamed variable in the code `nvertices` = `n`. In my workspace they were equal but that can be a reason why it did not work from your side. It is fixed now.

Comment: @Nick you should replace them with `%>%`. `|>` is the base R pipe operator introduced in 4.1

Comment: In your answer there are  some new symbols for me like "~" and "-.x".

Comment: @Nick It is a way to construct anonymous functions in the tidyverse family of packages. look here https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html